# How to add a conditional unique constraint in Liquibase?

Tags: liquibase, unique-constraint

Problem: When a user is deleted the associated record is not deleted from the database. Instead, I set `user.delete` column to `true`. Now I need to put a unique constraint on `user.email` but only for active users (not deleted).

How can I do this?

```yaml
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: add-user-unique-constraint
      author: me
      changes:
        - addUniqueConstraint:
            columnNames: email, delete
            constraintName: unique-email-not-deleted
            tableName: users
```

The above naive approach puts a composite constraint on (email, delete) columns, but it doesn't work because in the following flow user is blocked from deleting and creating an account:

1. register a new user with email "E"
2. delete the user with email "E"
3. register again new user with email "E"
4. delete the user with email "E" -> error: constraint violation
5. register new user with email "E" -> error: constraint violation

ps. databases are H2 and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is DB-specific and currently liquibase doesn't support it.

For `PostgreSQL` you may use direct SQL:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: add-user-unique-constraint
      author: me
      changes:
        - sql:
            "sql": "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_email_idx ON user (email) WHERE delete = 'false'"
```

however this will *NOT* work in `H2`.

Possible options for `H2`:

- if it's used in tests then you may migrate to `PostgreSQL` using [`testcontainers`](https://www.testcontainers.org/) technology (but your build environment will depend on `docker`)
- have custom changesets for `PostgreSQL` and `H2` - you may use [`preconditions`](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html)